# Why can't the reader, read my barcode 128?

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode

I have generated a code-bar 128 with jasperreport using iReport
the code is:

> A 1234567_ADH_20151224125543"

but the code-bar reader can't read the code

Can you tell me where is the problem?

Comment: We could only guess, please try to put together a [mcve], hence show us some minimal jrxml, tell us how you print it ecc.

Answer (score 0):

I chnange barcode 128 by QR code and it work very good

example for using QR code with jasper/Ireport : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AK5wTkwr718

thank you